# Vectorization and matrix multiplication by scalars

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am new to python/numpy. 
I need to do the following calculation:
for an array of discrete times t, calculate $e^{At}$ for a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$

What I did:

```
def calculate(t_,x_0,v_0,omega_0,c):

    # define A
    a_11,a_12, a_21, a_22=0,1,-omega_0^2,-c
    A =np.matrix([[a_11,a_12], [a_21, a_22]]) 
    print A
    # use vectorization 
    temps = np.array(t_)
    A_ = np.array([A  for k in  range (1,n+1,1)])
    temps*A_
    x_=scipy.linalg.expm(temps*A)
    v_=A*scipy.linalg.expm(temps*A)
    return x_,v_

n=10
omega_0=1
c=1
x_0=1
v_0=1
t_ = [float(5*k*np.pi/n)  for k in  range (1,n+1,1)]
x_, v_ = calculate(t_,x_0,v_0,omega_0,c)
```

However, I get this error when multiplying A_  (array containing n times A ) and temps (containg the times for which I want to calculate exp(At) :

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (10,2,2)

As I understand vectorization, each element in A_ would be multiplied by element at the same index from temps; but I think i don't get it right.
Any help/ comments much appreciated

Comment: Aside as I just noticed it; is there any particular reason to use `np.matrix`? The Numpy creators basically wish it didn't exist, so it's generally better to use a multidimensional `np.array` except for a very select number of operations.

Comment: @Azevedo I added the exponential. I didn't put it in the question because I wanted to isolate the problem

Comment: @roganjosh, the purpose of this line is to do vectorizarion. I thought I had to provide 2 numpy arrays of the same number of elements to be able to do vectorized  multiplication.  There was no particular reason for using np.matrix, I just used it because It was the first solution I found as I am new to numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure `numpy` calculation of `t_` is (creates an array instead of a list):

```
In [254]: t = 5*np.arange(1,n+1)*np.pi/n
In [255]: t
Out[255]: 
array([ 1.57079633,  3.14159265,  4.71238898,  6.28318531,  7.85398163,
        9.42477796, 10.99557429, 12.56637061, 14.13716694, 15.70796327])

In [256]: a_11,a_12, a_21, a_22=0,1,-omega_0^2,-c
In [257]: a_11
Out[257]: 0
In [258]: A = np.array([[a_11,a_12], [a_21, a_22]]) 
In [259]: A
Out[259]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [-3, -1]])
In [260]: t.shape
Out[260]: (10,)
In [261]: A.shape
Out[261]: (2, 2)
In [262]: A_ = np.array([A  for k in  range (1,n+1,1)])
In [263]: A_.shape
Out[263]: (10, 2, 2)
```

`A_` is `np.ndarray`.  I made `A` a `np.ndarray` as well; yours is `np.matrix`, but your `A_` will still be `np.ndarray`.  `np.matrix` can only be 2d, where as `A_` is 3d.

So `t * A` will be array elementwise multiplication, hence the broadcasting error,  `(10,) (10,2,2)`.

To do that elementwise multiplication right you need something like

```
In [264]: result = t[:,None,None]*A[None,:,:]
In [265]: result.shape
Out[265]: (10, 2, 2)
```

---

But if you want matrix multiplication of the (10,) with (10,2,2), then `einsum` does it easily:

```
In [266]: result1 = np.einsum('i,ijk', t, A_)
In [267]: result1
Out[267]: 
array([[   0.        ,   86.39379797],
       [-259.18139392,  -86.39379797]])
```

`np.dot` can't do it because its rule is 'last with 2nd to last'.  `tensordot` can, but I'm more comfortable with `einsum`.

But that `einsum` expression makes it obvious (to me) that I can get the same thing from the elementwise *, by summing on the 1st axis:

```
In [268]: (t[:,None,None]*A[None,:,:]).sum(axis=0)
Out[268]: 
array([[   0.        ,   86.39379797],
       [-259.18139392,  -86.39379797]])
```

Or `(t[:,None,None]*A[None,:,:]).cumsum(axis=0)` to get a 2x2 for each time.

Comment: You could use dot with rollaxis. Also, minor nitpick, but I'm pretty sure the class is called np.ndarray, not np.array. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
for t in np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, 20):
    print(expm(t*A))
```

No attempt at vectorization here. The `expm` function applies to one matrix at a time, and it surely takes the bulk of computation time. No need to worry about the cost of multiplying A by a scalar.